# Pull Requests are not recognised with Github Orgs on Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I've added new GitHub Organization Folder Plugin item on Jenkins. It successfully added all repos with all branches, but no pull requests. I see special tab for each repo there with 'Branches' and 'Pull Requests': branches are properly collected while Pull Requests are empty no matter what I tried.

What should I do for to get them?

I'm using latest Jenkins LTS (2.19.3 + GitHub Organization Folder Plugin 1.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pull requests are based on branches in the origin repository (instead of a fork) they will be skipped.

If you want PR coming from origin branches to be processed, then you have to activate `Build origin PRs (merged with base branch)` in the additional settings section in the branch source configuration.